# Ratio of colors to produce white in color television

Tags: tv

If you consult pretty much any book on the theory of color television, it says that because the human eye is more sensitive to green than red or blue, the reference white for color television has been chosen as a mixture of 30% red, 59% green and 11% blue. Surely, though, if the eye is most sensitive to green, it is the proportion of red and blue that should be boosted, not green?

Comment: Context and quote sources missing.

Comment: On a Normalized display Black is 0,0,0, White is 256,256,256 and grey is anything with equal RGB values between those ranges.

Comment: For full range computer graphics it would be 0 to 255. For limited range signals used in digital video such as blu-ray players, the range is 16 to 235.

Comment: @dgwp, use the answer box for answering, not for comments

Answer (score 1):

No, you are interpreting it the opposite way. Those are the (approximate and really old) ratios for combining RGB signals to make a greyscale signal, or brightness value. So as you can see, eyes are most sensitive to green so it contributes the most to the brightness signal, and least sensitive to blue so it makes least contribution to brightness signal.

The reference white point is D65 (6500K) and when you split a greyscale signal into RGB components, you get equal RGB values. 100% white is 100% R, 100% G and 100% B.

And to convert RGB to white, the 100% RGB adds up to 100% white, as 30%+59%+11%=100%.

Comment: +1 [This](https://www.itu.int/dms_pub/itu-r/opb/rep/R-REP-BT.2380-2015-PDF-E.pdf) paper does a pretty good job of describing it. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacAdam_ellipse) is also interesting.

Comment: Current HDR TVs implement the BT.2100 standard or at least BT.2020. BT.709 is still used for HD signals and SRGB is based on it, and BT.601 is used for SD signals.

Comment: Justme, you say that "eyes are most sensitive to green so it contributes the most to the brightness signal", but this does not help my understanding. Can you expand on your explanation?

Comment: @dgwp it would help to know what you don't understand so I'd know which way to expand my answer.

Comment: Basically... if the eye is more sensitive to green, why does it need more green in the signal?

Comment: @dgwp you still have it the wrong way. It does not need more green, on the contrary. Because eyes are most sensitive to green, you need more red light to appear as bright as the green light does. Or to put it another way, you need less green light to match the brightness of red light. The 100% green light provides 59% of the brightness experience, and 100% red light only 30% of the brighness. You would need 197% of red light, almost 2x as bright as the green light to match their brightness. And about 536% or 5.36 times more blue light than green light to match their brightnesses.

Comment: @dgwp I think I got confused by the same thing as you did. White does not correspond to a specific ratio of RGB. There are many ratios and RGB that will still be interpreted as the "color" white. The ratios in TVs is just one variation of white that maximizes energy efficiency by using more green to boost brightness.